# How can I initialize an object inside a constructor in C++?

Tags: c++

I've created the player class, with a RectangleShape object as a private object, and I want to initialize it in the .cpp contstructor, but it doesn't work.

player.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Player {
    Player(int x, int y);

    private:
        int x;
        int y;
        sf::RectangleShape rect;

    public:
        void Move(int x, int y);
        void Update();
        void Render(sf::Window window);
};
```

And here is the player.cpp:

```
#include "player.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

Player::Player(int x, int y) {
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->rect(sf::Vector3f(x, y)); //Sorry, this one is the one that doesn't work.
}
```

Comment: *How* doesn't it work? What problems do you get? Do you get build error? What error? Do you get crashes or similar problems when running? Do you get unexpected results? Please elaborate! And please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [Does not work](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/) is not an useful problem description.

Comment: By the way, you might want to search for and read about *c++ constructor initializer lists*. Learning about them should solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry, it's already updated.

Answer (score 2):

You should use constructor initialiser list. For example like this;

Class definition

```
class Player 
{
    Player(int x, int y);

    private:
        int x;
        int y;
        //other code...
};
```

Class implementation

```
    Player(int x, int y)
    :x(x), y(y)
    {
        //Constructor body
    }
```

Comment: It didn't sove the problem because "this" is what gives me the error. Says: call of an object of a class type without appropiate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type.

Comment: @Coconaut_ Extrapolate what is shown in this answer, how do you think the initialization of the member `rect` look if done this way?

Comment: I know it's not the right way to initializate it, but I don't know how to do it the right way

Comment: @Coconaut_ The right way *is* what is show here, but to "extrapolate" you need to do e.g. `Player(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y), rect(sf::Vector3f(x, y)) {}` Did you even *try* something like that?

Comment: sf::RectangleShape pre_rect(sf::Vector2f(30, 30));
 this->rect = pre_rect;